# How to package 2 third-party dll's

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm reading through the nuget documentation and I don't completely understand how nuget works.

I have 2 third party dll's that I have been asked to turn into a nuget package, so that our local developers can just install them to a project via nuget. This would be something that we would host locally.

Does this mean I just create a project in vs and drop the dll's in the project or do I use something like the package explorer.

I apologize in advance if this is a silly question, however I am an absolute beginner when it comes to Nuget, etc..

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do those 3rd party ones have nuget packages?

Comment: Not that I can see, it is for some pdf libraries we purchased.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create nuget package with multiple DLLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486651/create-nuget-package-with-multiple-dlls)

Answer (score 13):

The simplest and fastest way to get a nuget package up and running is to just fire up package explorer --> create a new package --> drag and drop your dlls into the "Package Contents" area, it'll ask you whether you want the dlls in the "lib" folder, which you do --> create a bit of metadata about the package, ie give it a description and version and whatnot, and then just save it.

After you save it, you can then copy the .nupkg file to a shared location - the file system on a centralised server is fine if you have access to one, and then setup access to this "feed" (ie, the shared folder) in visual studio (tools --> options --> Package Manager --> Package Sources), thus:

[image: Visual Studio]

Or if you want to host the packages over http you can follow the instructions here: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/master/README.markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be to use Nuget.exe spec, pack commands to quickly create package. 
More details here @ http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference