# Why doesn't nuget include the referenced project when packing?

Tags: nuget

I have reproduced this issue in the following simple scenario

- LibB - project

  - ClassB
- LibA - project

  - ClassA that references ClassB

Now I want to create a nuget package of `LibA` and run:

```
nuget pack LibA.csproj
```

This works fine, but when I check the nuget package I can't find a `LibB.dll` in the lib folders as I expected. Why not?

I'm using version 2.2 of Nuget.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NuGet 2.5 now has a `-includereferencedprojects` option, more details can be found here : [NuGet Command-Line Interface (CLI) Reference | Microsoft Docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command)
I download the latest version of `nuget.exe` from `nuget.org/nuget.exe` or by `nuget update -self`.

Comment: what if the referenced is a dll itself? It doesn't seem to include the dependent DLL.

Comment: I'm also having a trouble with this. The option does add project references to the nuget package, but not references to pre-compiled DLLs. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?

Comment: @PhilipAtz I've created a utility, that deals with the problem at a different level: https://github.com/dittodhole/powershell-nuget-packager

Comment: I can't get this to work at all. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5720