# VSTS Nuget packager task - how to generate package with all dependent project dlls included

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've 4 project structure below:

1. Core
2. Infrastructure
3. Ship
4. Ship.aspnet

Where when I create a nuget package from ship project, it should contain all the dependent project dlls i.e. 1, 2 and 4.

At the moment when I create a VSTS Nuget Packager Task pointing to ship project, it generates the *.ship nuget package. However, when I consume this package the compiler complains that core, infrastructure and ship.aspnet dlls are missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486651/create-nuget-package-with-multiple-dlls) SO question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include -IncludeReferencedProjects argument.

[image]